# Spring REST MultipartFile file is always null when do upload file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "{fileName:.+}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity<ResponseEnvelope<String>> uploadFile(
         @RequestParam("ownerId") Long ownerId, 
         @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,
         @RequestBody MultipartFile file)
         throws Exception {
    ResponseEnvelope<String> env;
    if(null == certFileContent) {
        env = new ResponseEnvelope<String>("fail");
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseEnvelope<String>>(env, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    service.uploadCertificate(ownerId, fileName, certFileContent.getBytes());
    env = new ResponseEnvelope<String>("success");
    return new ResponseEntity<ResponseEnvelope<String>>(env, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Why I always get the file value is null, I've configure the multipart support,see below,

Comment: Have you also added the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your HTML `<form />` tag (see http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2)?

Comment: I use the Rest client to do test, also have choose the "multipart/form-data" for content-typem, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The file should be binded to a `RequestParam` instead of the `RequestBody` as follows:

```
public ResponseEntity<ResponseEnvelope<String>> uploadFile(
         @RequestParam("ownerId") Long ownerId, 
         @PathVariable("fileName") String fileName,
         @RequestParam(value = "file") MultipartFile file)
```

This would correspond with the following HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="some action" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="35"/>
</form>
```

Then in your dispatcher configuration specify the `CommonsMultiPartResolver`

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind response, I've tried use @RequestParam, but I get another issue, "{"error":{"status":400,"message":"An unknown error has occurred during the execution of this request.","errorParams":{"exceptionMessage":"Required MultiPart parameter 'file' is not present"}}}", I've also specify the commonsMultiPartResolver in my config, thanks much.

Comment: Question has been resolved, the problem is that I need specify the parameter name...when I do post, thanks.

Comment: @Berry2081898 I'm having this trouble right now, what do you mean with specifying the parameter name when doing POST? I'm doing the post request using AJAX. I will appreciate any help from you, thanks in advanced.
Here's the link to my stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27772803/uploading-files-using-the-spring-framework-and-jquery-upload-file-plugin-issue

Comment: @Berry2081898 or maybe you could also post the answer to your own question so everyone else can see it too!

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me,

Previously my `input` field was defined as,

```
<input type="file" />
```

I was getting null file with the above line but when I added the `name="file"` everything worked fine!

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

Hope this helps!