# Uploading files using the Spring Framework and jquery-upload-file plugin issue

Tags: ajax, spring, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I am having trouble uploading files via **AJAX** from my web-client to my Server. I am using the following *jQuery* library in the client-side to do the file upload: https://github.com/hayageek/jquery-upload-file

In the server-side, I'm using *Spring Framework* and I have followed the following *Spring* Tutorial to build my Service: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/

At first, my server method looked like this (*file* was defined as **@RequestParam**):

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
    //functionality here
}
```

but every time I submitted the Upload form I got a **Bad Request** message from the Server, and my `handleFileUpload()` method was never called.

After that, I realized the file was not being sent as a Request Parameter so I defined `file` as **@RequestBody**, and now my method looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(@RequestBody("file") MultipartFile file){
    //functionality here
}
```

Now `handleFileUpload()` is called every time the Upload form is submitted, but I am getting a `NullPointerException` every time I want to manipulate *file*.

I want to avoid submitting the form by default, I just want to do it through AJAX straight to the Server. Does anybody know what could be happening here?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I know, it's something I've stopped doing in my latest posts. Thank you anyway for the advice given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may try changing the signature of the method to

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(MultipartHttpServletRequest request){
    Iterator<String> iterator = request.getFileNames();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String fileName = iterator.next();
        MultipartFile multipartFile = request.getFile(fileName);
        byte[] file = multipartFile.getBytes();
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

this works with jQuery File Upload in our webapp. If for some reason this does 
not work for you, you may try to isolate the problem, by inspecting the HTTP
request issued by the jQuery File Upload (for example, with Fiddler), and debugging the response starting from Spring 
DispatcherServlet.

Comment: This worked as well when trying to upload files by using an Ajax request with the axios library to a Sprint Boot backend.